# Update SQL Records Based on Joined Select

Tags: sql-server

This seems really straight forward, and I think I just want to validate and ensure that I'm doing this correctly.

Basically I want to run an UPDATE on these records:

```
SELECT     contact.company, contact.coaddress, contact.costate, contact.cocity, contact.cozip, contact.phonebusiness, dial.AgentID, dial.Attempts, dial.CRC
FROM         contact LEFT OUTER JOIN
                  dial ON contact.DialID = dial.DialID
WHERE     (dial.AgentID > '-1') AND (contact.cozip LIKE '600%' OR
                  contact.cozip LIKE '601%' OR
                  contact.cozip LIKE '606%' OR
                  contact.cozip LIKE '608%' OR
                  contact.cozip LIKE '605%' OR
                  contact.cozip LIKE '604%' OR
                  contact.cozip LIKE '613%' OR
                  contact.cozip LIKE '611%')
```

I get back my correct results on the SELECT statement.  I need to now UPDATE those records:

```
UPDATE    dial
SET              ProjectID = '60'
FROM         dial INNER JOIN
                  contact ON dial.DialID = contact.DialID
WHERE     (dial.AgentID > '-1') AND (contact.cozip LIKE '600%' OR
                  contact.cozip LIKE '601%' OR
                  contact.cozip LIKE '606%' OR
                  contact.cozip LIKE '608%' OR
                  contact.cozip LIKE '605%' OR
                  contact.cozip LIKE '604%' OR
                  contact.cozip LIKE '613%' OR
                  contact.cozip LIKE '611%')
```

Does this look correct?  Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: put the update statement in a transaction and test it. Looks fine but nothing prevents you from testing in the safety of a transaction first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this looks correct.

There are some LIKE tricks and I like aliases personally. The alias d makes it clear which table is being updated in the JOIN. The [] in the LIKE means a range or set

```
UPDATE
    d
SET 
    ProjectID = '60'
FROM
    dial d
    INNER JOIN
    contact ON d.DialID = contact.DialID
WHERE
   (d.AgentID > -1) --edit, int. Not varchar
   AND 
   (contact.cozip LIKE '60[016854]%' OR contact.cozip LIKE '61[13]%')
```

Should AgentID be the number -1 too?

Comment: No, AgentID should contain 0 and above, anything below 0 is not part of the criteria.

Comment: @gbn will mssql be able to use indexes with those wildchars combined with 'or'. I had some bad experiences using wildchars combined with 'or' ?

Comment: @t-clausen.dk: maybe, maybe not... Your LEFT will definitely not use an index.

Comment: @RogueSpear00: I meant, why do you have a string in the query? is AgentID varchar?

Comment: I know my method will not use index. I was wondering if your script will solve some of my RL code issues

Comment: @RogueSpear00: please note my edit then for the AgentID check

Comment: @gbn - Ah! It just clicked. Don't know why I had it in ticks. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 1):

That looks like the correct syntax to me for Deleting or Updating based on a JOIN.

Note that you could alternately use a subquery and the IN operator, e.g. "UPDATE dial SET ProjectID = '60' WHERE DialID in (SELECT DialID from dial...)".